# How to create objects with named keys in R?

Tags: json, r, hashmap, hashtable

I want to create and pass around objects in R with named keys (the values will most likely be data frames, but may be other things).

In JavaScript this is easy, you just write `{ key1 : value1, key2 : value2 }` and `value1` and `value2` can be any type of object, function, etc.

The [`rjson` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html) seems to be able to do something similar:

```
> x = fromJSON('{"a":1,"b":2}')
> x
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

> x$a
[1] 1
```

What kind of R objects are these, and how can I create them in my own code?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What objects? What code?

Comment: It sounds like you want to store data frames in a list.

Comment: @hrbrmstr can a list have named keys?

Comment: Ah, [looks like it can](http://statmethods.net/input/datatypes.html).  I didn't even think to check.  R is such a strange language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't think to check this until @hrbrmstr's comment, but R lists can have named keys:

```
x = list(a=1, b=2)
```

This is exactly what I wanted.